# Consumir web service

Tags: java

Venho como uma ideia de implantar em um sistema que estou montando um web service, onde o usuário informa o cep, e os campos do endereço se completassem. Contudo não acho nada a respeito de como fazer isso em aplicações desktop.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que gostaria é que, quando o campo cep fosse preenchido os seguintes campos em cinza se autocompletassem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue código usado para consumir web service
OBS: não utilizei o do via cep, encontrei um exemplo ótimo que funcionou perfeitamente com pouco código, porém é necessário adicionar uma biblioteca externa chamada "dom4j-1.6.1"

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.dom4j.Document;
import org.dom4j.DocumentException;
import org.dom4j.Element;
import org.dom4j.io.SAXReader;

public class SearchForZipCode 
{
    // Properties
    private String state;
    private String city;
    private String neighborhood;
    private String street;

    private int result = 0;
    private String resultText;

    // Constructor
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public SearchForZipCode(String zipCode)
    {
        try 
        {
            URL url = new URL("http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?cep=" + zipCode + "&formato=xml");

            Document document = getDocumento(url);

            Element root = document.getRootElement();

            for (Iterator i = root.elementIterator(); i.hasNext();) 
            {
                Element element = (Element) i.next();

                if(element.getQualifiedName().equals("uf")) setState(element.getText());

                if(element.getQualifiedName().equals("cidade")) setCity(element.getText());

                if(element.getQualifiedName().equals("bairro")) setNeighborhood(element.getText());

                if(element.getQualifiedName().equals("logradouro")) setStreet(element.getText());

                if(element.getQualifiedName().equals("resultado")) setResult(Integer.parseInt(element.getText()));

                if(element.getQualifiedName().equals("resultado_txt")) setResultText(element.getText());    
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Document getDocumento(URL url) throws DocumentException 
    {
        SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
        Document document = reader.read(url);

        return document;
    } 


    public String getState() 
    {
        return state;
    }
    public void setState(String state) 
    {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getCity() 
    {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) 
    {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getNeighborhood() 
    {
        return neighborhood;
    }
    public void setNeighborhood(String neighborhood) 
    {
        this.neighborhood = neighborhood;
    }

    public String getStreet() 
    {
        return street;
    }
    public void setStreet(String street) 
    {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public int getResult() 
    {
        return result;
    }
    public void setResult(int result) 
    {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public String getResultText() 
    {
        return resultText;
    }
    public void setResultText(String resultText) 
    {
        this.resultText = resultText;
    }
}
```

Após o construir essa classe, basta instanciar a mesma e jogar as informações nos respectivos campos usando o "setText".

Answer (score 2):

O webservice [ViaCEP](https://viacep.com.br/) é o que você procura.

Exemplo chamada passando o cep no parâmetro:

https://viacep.com.br/ws/88111500/json/

**Resposta:**

```
{
  "cep": "88111-500",
  "logradouro": "Rua Otto Júlio Malina",
  "complemento": "",
  "bairro": "Ipiranga",
  "localidade": "São José",
  "uf": "SC",
  "unidade": "",
  "ibge": "4216602",
  "gia": ""
}
```

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/131255)

Comment: @Marconi, eu não sei como poderia colaborar com partes essenciais ou código aqui, já que a pergunta apenas pede um Webservice capaz de consumir os dados. Alguma sugestão para melhorar minha resposta neste aspecto?

Comment: Cleber, coloque partes relevantes do código que podem ajudá-lo a encontra uma solução para o seu problema. Respostas só com link geralmente são excluídas.

Comment: Nestes casos use um comentário.

Comment: Certo!
Estou com o acesso ao ViaCEP bloqueado no momento. No horário do almoço irei acessar e complementar a resposta!

Comment: Certo estou estudando o código no gitlab, assim que tiver sucesso posto aqui como o código ficou